# Cannot get string from StringStream

Tags: delphi

I am sending an HTTP Get request to Google's Map API, and I fill my StringStream with the response. However, when I try to read from the stream, I am just presented with an empty string ''.

```
{ Attempts to get JSON back from Google's Directions API }
function GetJSONString_OrDie(url : string) : string;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Buffer: TStringStream;
begin
  {Sets up SSL}
  SSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  {Creates an HTTP request}
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  {Sets the HTTP request to use SSL}
  lHTTP.IOHandler := SSL;

  {Set up the buffer}
  Buffer := TStringStream.Create(Result);
  {Attempts to get JSON back from Google's Directions API}
  lHTTP.Get(url, Buffer);

  Result:= Buffer.ReadString(Buffer.Size); //An empty string is put into Result


  finally
    {Frees up the HTTP object}
    lHTTP.Free;
    {Frees up the SSL object}
    SSL.Free;

end;
```

Why am I getting an empty string back, when I can see that the StringStream `Buffer` has plenty of data (size of 32495 after the Get is called).

I've tested my call, and I am returned with valid JSON.

Comment: Simply return `Result := Buffer.DataString` to avoid stream position mistakes like this.

Comment: Yes, what `TLama` said - I was about to say. No need to use `Read` if you want the full contents.

Comment: Sweet! That'll come in handy in the future. @TLama, make that an answer and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe first set `Buffer.Position := 0`?

Comment: I would have figured `.ReadString` would read from the beginning if no position was supplied.

Comment: "would have figured"  Maybe helps to think of a stream as having a "cursor" which is where reading and writing will occur from.  Unless you take action to avoid it, writing will continue where it last left off, and the "cursor" will be left one position beyond the end of the written data.

Comment: @Acorn: No. When a stream is written to, the current position always remains at the end of the stream in case you're writing more data. If you want to read from the stream after it is written to, you need to set the position back to the start of the stream. This is by design and has been the case since Delphi 1.

Comment: @JerryDodge some streams do not support backward positioning, for example streams which encapsulate TCP sockets

Answer (score 5):

First, you are using `TStringStream` to receive the response data.  If you are using Delphi 2009+, DO NOT do that!  `TStringStream` is tied to a *specific encoding* that has to be declared in the *constructor* before the stream is populated with data, and it cannot be changed dynamically.  The default encoding is `TEncoding.Default`, which represents the OS default encoding.  If the HTTP response uses a *different* encoding, the data will not decode to a `String` correctly.

Second, you are not seeking the stream's `Position` back to 0 before calling `ReadString()`.  An easier way to retrieve a `TStringStream`'s content as a decoded `String` is to use the `DataString` property instead, which ignores the `Position` property and returns the entire stream content as a whole:

```
Result := Buffer.DataString;
```

Third, you are doing too much manual work.  `TIdHTTP.Get()` has an overloaded version that returns a decoded `String`.  The benefit of using this method is that it uses the actual charset of the response, rather than the charset of a `TStringStream`:

```
function GetJSONString_OrDie(const URL: string): string;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  {Creates an HTTP request}
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    {Sets the HTTP request to use SSL}
    lHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(lHTTP);    
    {Attempts to get JSON back from Google's Directions API}
    Result := lHTTP.Get(URL);
  finally
    {Frees up the HTTP object}
    lHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Which can be simplified further if you are using an up-to-date version of Indy (see [this blog post](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changeLog/20141222.aspx) for details):

```
function GetJSONString_OrDie(const URL: string): string;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
begin
  {Creates an HTTP request}
  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    {Attempts to get JSON back from Google's Directions API}
    Result := lHTTP.Get(URL);
  finally
    {Frees up the HTTP object}
    lHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```